# Set text selection highlight

Tags: android, textview

We can get selection range in android TextView like this :

```
TextView childView;
...
int end=childView.getSelectionEnd()
```

but how can we set it, in a way like below:

```
childView.setSelection(start,end);
```

Comment: Why not go to Java. Get the string from textview, convert to char array and replace the required characters?

Comment: I need to show selection to user and let him modify it